# Change Prior Pymc3 with from_formula

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I'm working on a dataset from Kaggle (the one on Human ressources) I am trying to implement some bayesian statistics (logistic regression) but I don't understand how to change the prior on this model (I want the intercept to be an uninformative gaussian and the laplace for all the other predictors)

```
import pymc3 as pm

priors = {"Intercept": pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=100),
      "Regressor": pm.Laplace('beta', mu=0, b=np.sqrt(2))
          }

with pm.Model() as logistic_model:
     pm.glm.GLM.from_formula('left ~ satisfaction_level + last_evaluation \
                        + number_project + average_montly_hours \
                        + time_spend_company + Work_accident + promotion_last_5years\
                        + sales + salary', df, family=pm.glm.families.Binomial(), priors = priors)
    trace_logistic_model = pm.sample(4000)
```

And the error message:

```
TypeError: No model on context stack, which is needed to instantiate distributions. Add variable inside a 'with model:' block, or use the '.dist' syntax for a standalone distribution.
```

I've tried to use the "dist" but it doesn't work

Thanks for your help

Update:

I have change my code to the following:

```
with pm.Model() as logistic_model:

    priors = {"Intercept": pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=100),
      "Regressor": pm.Laplace('beta', mu=0, b=np.sqrt(2))
          }

    pm.glm.GLM.from_formula('left ~ satisfaction_level + last_evaluation \
                        + number_project + average_montly_hours \
                        + time_spend_company + Work_accident + promotion_last_5years\
                        + sales + salary', df, family=pm.glm.families.Binomial(), priors = priors)
    trace_logistic_model = pm.sample(4000)
```

Now I Have this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-e3566f815877> in <module>()
      5               }
      6 
----> 7     pm.glm.GLM.from_formula('left ~ satisfaction_level + last_evaluation                             + number_project + average_montly_hours                             + time_spend_company + Work_accident + promotion_last_5years                            + sales + salary', df, family=pm.glm.families.Binomial(), priors = priors)
      8     trace_logistic_model = pm.sample(4000)

/home/glouis/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymc3/glm/linear.py in from_formula(cls, formula, data, priors, vars, family, name, model)
    134         labels = x.design_info.column_names
    135         return cls(np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)[:, 0], intercept=False, labels=labels,
--> 136                    priors=priors, vars=vars, family=family, name=name, model=model)
    137 
    138 glm = GLM

/home/glouis/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymc3/model.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    238         instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    239         with instance:  # appends context
--> 240             instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    241         return instance
    242 

/home/glouis/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymc3/glm/linear.py in __init__(self, x, y, intercept, labels, priors, vars, family, name, model)
    111         super(GLM, self).__init__(
    112             x, y, intercept=intercept, labels=labels,
--> 113             priors=priors, vars=vars, name=name, model=model
    114         )
    115 

/home/glouis/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymc3/glm/linear.py in __init__(self, x, y, intercept, labels, priors, vars, name, model)
     57                         dist=priors.get(
     58                             name,
---> 59                             self.default_intercept_prior
     60                         )
     61                     )

/home/glouis/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymc3/model.py in Var(self, name, dist, data, total_size)
    750                 with self:
    751                     var = FreeRV(name=name, distribution=dist,
--> 752                                  total_size=total_size, model=self)
    753                 self.free_RVs.append(var)
    754             else:

/home/glouis/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymc3/model.py in __init__(self, type, owner, index, name, distribution, total_size, model)
   1117         if distribution is not None:
   1118             self.dshape = tuple(distribution.shape)
-> 1119             self.dsize = int(np.prod(distribution.shape))
   1120             self.distribution = distribution
   1121             self.tag.test_value = np.ones(

/home/glouis/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in prod(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   2513             pass
   2514         else:
-> 2515             return prod(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)
   2516 
   2517     return _methods._prod(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,

TypeError: prod() got an unexpected keyword argument 'out'
```

Comment: You should be able to just move the definition of `priors` into the context manager -- `pm.Normal` and `pm.Laplace` need to be instantiated inside the `with pm.Model()` block.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this code

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np

df = ...
# pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=100) is random variable, named `alpha`,
# pm.Normal.dist(...) is distribution object used to create random variables
# 
# From https://docs.pymc.io/api/glm.html
#
# use Intercept key for defining Intercept prior
#    defaults to Flat.dist()
#
# use Regressor key for defining default prior for all regressors
#    defaults to Normal.dist(mu=0, tau=1.0E-6)

priors = {"Intercept": pm.Normal.dist(mu=0, sd=100),
          "Regressor": pm.Laplace.dist(mu=0, b=np.sqrt(2))
          }

with pm.Model() as logistic_model:
    pm.glm.GLM.from_formula('left ~ satisfaction_level + last_evaluation \
                        + number_project + average_montly_hours \
                        + time_spend_company + Work_accident +     promotion_last_5years\
                        + sales + salary', df, family=pm.glm.families.Binomial(), priors = priors)
    trace_logistic_model = pm.sample(4000)
```